# How to change variable in API from list and create dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, api

Below is code using the TD Ameritrade API. Before I jump into this it is important to note that I left out a piece of the code (td_consumer_key) because it is a personal key code and is needed to access the API.

The code below pulls historical stock price data for a specified stock (stock_ticker). I have about 500 stock tickers in the form of a list that I would like to pull historical data for using the API. The problem is that the API can only go stock by stock, I cannot simply put the list as the stock_ticker variable and pull all the data for all the stocks. I would also like to put all this data for all the stocks into a data frame.

```
endpoint = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{stock_ticker}/pricehistory?periodType={periodType}&period={period}&frequencyType={frequencyType}&frequency={frequency}'
full_url = endpoint.format(stock_ticker='ABNB',periodType='year',period=1,frequencyType='weekly',frequency=1)
page = requests.get(url=full_url,
                    params={'apikey' : td_consumer_key})
content = json.loads(page.content)
print(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through your list and append results to another list as you go, for example:

```
scraped_content = list()
for ticker in list_of_tickers:  # Replace with whatever you list variable name is.
    full_url = endpoint.format(stock_ticker=ticker, periodType='year', period=1, frequencyType='weekly', frequency=1)
    page = requests.get(url=full_url, params={'apikey': td_consumer_key})
    content = json.loads(page.content)
    scraped_content.append(content)
```